# Rails Clickable link_to entire table row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, clickable

I am new to rails and i want to make a whole row clickable with link_to. I am wondering what am I doing wrong with this code ? Nothing is clickable here.  Do I have to use Javascript ? I would love some help.

```
      <% @courses.each do |course|%>
        <tr>
          <%= link_to managers_course_path(course) do %>
            <td class="name"><%= course.activity.name %></td>
            <td class="day"><%= course.starts_at.strftime("%A %e %B") %></td>
            <td class="start"><%= course.starts_at.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
            <td class="end"><%= course.ends_at.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: The permitted contents inside an `<tr>` is `Zero or more <td> and/or <th> elements; script-supporting elements (<script> and <template>) are also allowed`. The browser is ignoring the `<A>` tag since its invalid HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

Comment: For the sake of accessibility you should just provide a normal link in a `<td>` or not use a table.